# How do i check an adjacent cell is non empty if one cell on the same row is empty pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science

I've been trying for 2 days now I cant seem to figure out how do I check it and return values if its empty. For example if a roll no. in roll number column is filled I want to check the same row has a name under name column. If not, I want to return "NO".

```
value2=u_op.loc[u_op['RollNo'].astype(str).notnull()!=u_op['Name'].astype(str).notnull(), 'Name']
```

trying to get nan as an output if roll no is not empty and name is empty but not working

Answer (score 0):

here is one way
here is one way

Understanding: ROLLNo is NOT Null and NAME is NULL, return NO. Else leave as is

```
u_op['Name'] = (u_op['Name'].mask(u_op['RollNo'].astype(str).notnull() & 
                                  u_op['Name']  .astype(str).isnull()
                                  , 'No'))
```

**PS:** Question with reproducible example would have allowed to validate and post the result.  Refer to guidelines here   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example